# AngularJS error when trying to update a record

Tags: c#, oracle, angularjs

I just started learning angularjs and I'm stuck on saving records. I have a form with textboxes to enter state, companyId, and rate that are prepopulated with data for a selected record. When I click Save button, I get "POST ~/AppWeb/AppApi/UpdateRecord 404 (Not Found)". I'm using Oracle database. I have the following code:

.js:

```
.factory("Services", function (Api) {           
this.saveRecord = function (data) {
    if (data.Id > 0) {
        return Api.save("AppApi/UpdateRecord", data);
    }
};  
return this;
})

.controller("ViewSaveController", function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, State, Services) {
Services.getRecord($routeParams.id).success(function (d) {
    $scope.model = d;
});

$scope.save = function (controller) {
    Services.saveRecord($scope.model).success(function (d, s, h, c) {
        //redirect to the list view
    });
};  
})
```

ApiControllder.cs:

```
public WorkRates UpdateRecord()
{
try
{
    var q = new DemoQueries();
    return q.UpdateRecord();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

PartialQueries.cs:

```
public WorkRates UpdateRecord(int id, string state, string companyId, string rate)
{
var sql = "update ratestable set state = :state, companyId= :companyId, rate = :rate where id = :id";
var db = Db.Load(sql);

db.AddParameter(":id", id);
db.AddParameter(":state", state);
db.AddParameter(":companyId", companyId);
db.AddParameter(":rate", rate);

db.DoExecute();

var l = db.GetList<WorkRates>().FirstOrDefault();
return l;
}
```

I'm not sure why I get this error message. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the 404 error or **Not Found** error because the POST that your form is performing is not reaching any valid endpoint of your web app. Basically the endpoint "AppWeb/AppApi/UpdateRecord" does not exist.

Have you tried replacing "ApexApi/UpdateRecord" by "AppApi/UpdateRecord" in your code? 
I am not an expert in angular but it looks like it is an issue with the routes. This article it may be helpful. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/